# How to use Kafka Streams/Connect to keep MySQL database in Sync to HBASE?

Tags: mysql, hbase, apache-kafka-connect

I want to synchronize HBASE Database as per the update triggers generated by the MySQL with the help of Kafka Streams or Kafka Connect. Any suggestions on its possibility and how is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Stream your data out of MySQL using Kafka Connect with [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) into Kafka, and then stream to Hbase using Kafka Connect with [kafka-connect-hbase](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hbase)

Learn more about Kafka Connect here: http://rmoff.dev/ksldn19-kafka-connect